# How to Fix Error UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\dtSearch Developer\bin\dtsjava.dll: The operating system cannot run %1

Tags: java, windows-xp, java-native-interface, dtsearch

I am working with J2EE.I have installed the dtSearch Engine Tool on my windows xp,I have set all the environment varibles for this still I got the above Error on my console.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the "msvcr71.dll" in your Windows\System directory? Do you have a 64bit OS with 32bit JRE?

Comment: I have 32 bit OS and 32 bit JRE,again I have MSVCR71.dll in my Windows/system32 directory.